# Is there a Apache module can fully log HTTP requests, in a non processed way?

Tags: apache-2.4, logging, http-headers

I'm looking for an Apache module that is able to log the RAW content of HTTP requests, unprocessed. Here is one example :

```
POST https://foobar/ HTTP/1.1
Host: foorbar
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 357
...
Accept-Language: en,en-US;q=0.9,de-DE;q=0.8,de;q=0.7
Cookie: sessiontid=....

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> ...  </s:Envelope>
```

What I have tried so far :

- apache built-in log: it can only log some specific HTTP headers (the ones specified in the custom format).
- `mod_log_forensic` + `mod_unique_id` : it dumps all the HTTP headers but not the body/POST data. In the example above all HTTP headers would be logged, but not the SOAP enveloppe. A great feature is to be able to link those logs with regular apache logs, using unique ID.
- `mod_dumpio` : it only dumps POST data to error.log, in a unfriendly way (multiple lines per request, all decorated with additional info). Furthermore, there is no way to bind that info with a unique ID.
- `mod_dumpost` : better than dumpio as it logs everything in one line, without decorating it with extra data. Still, there is no support for unique ID. Therefore it's difficult to match that info with HTTP headers (which are logged in a different place).

Comment: I would think that most people simply run a packet capture and subsequent protocol decoders (when they need to debug a web application and don't control the clients) and/or possibly also something like mitmproxy and/or  browser plugins when  do they (also/only) control the client.

Comment: @HBruijn Do you have packet capture tool to suggest for Cent OS operating system ? Decoding SSL protocol and defragmenting packets is a must. It's not possible to install something client side.

Comment: Capture with something like `tcpdump`  and then copy the capture to your workstation where you run something like wireshark (which you can load your servers TLS certificates into for full protocol decoding)